# is there a way to reverse the effect of atan?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

imagine i have this

```
     Math.atan(RH/RL)
     //output for 5,3 : 1.0303768265243125
```

but is it possible to reverse the effect of Math atan without the reference to starting point & reach the initial input value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Math.tan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/tan)

```js
console.log(Math.atan(5 / 3));
console.log(Math.tan(1.0303768265243125));
```